# How to create an unnumbered footnote that ignores memoir's footmarkstyle

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I want to create an unnumbered footnote at the start of my chapter but I don't know how I can avoid the style that is implemented for my numbered footnotes. Currently I have:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\blindnote}{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext} % define unnumbered footnote 
\makeatother

\footmarkstyle{#1. \hfill}           % marker flushed left
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.6em}    % create indentation space for marker
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-1.6em}     % set text to margin

\begin{document}
    \null\vfill
    \blindnote{This should be flushed left without indentation and period.}

Note\footnote{This looks like it should.}
\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

but it should look like this

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% define unnumbered footnote 
\newcommand{\blindnote}[1]{%
  \def\@thefnmark{}%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\footmarksep}{0pt}%
  \footmarkstyle{}%
  \@footnotetext{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\footmarkstyle{#1. \hfill}           % marker flushed left
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.6em}    % create indentation space for marker
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-1.6em}     % set text to margin

\begin{document}
    \null\vfill
    \blindnote{\lipsum[1]}

Note\footnote{This looks like it should.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was a really good suggestion but the second line of the blindnote went into the margin. I added the line `\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}%` to solve that problem.

Comment: @cktai Thanks. I've updated my answer to add `\setlength{\footmarksep}{0pt}`.