# Footnote without reference in text

Tags: footnotes

I want to have a footnote (numbered) in the footnote section but don't want the footnote mark to appear in the written text. How can I achieve this behaviour? If I use `\footnotetext` the numbering doesn't stay consistent (once used and not referenced, i.e. no matching `\footnotemark`, the number stays the same).

Comment: This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548568/how-to-create-an-unnumbered-footnote-that-ignores-memoirs-footmarkstyle may helps you

Comment: This syntax is possible `\footnotetext[1]{text}`

Comment: @anis But this means one hardcodes the label, not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `\footnotemark`, but want the footnote number continued, you have to use `\stepcounter{footnote}` to increase the `footnote` counter yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This was the first lipsum paragraph}

\lipsum[2]\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{\label{ftn}We also have had assecond one.}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{And a third one.}

The invisible footnote was number \ref{ftn}.
\end{document}
```

Usually you don't need `\refstepcounter`, even if you set a label inside `\footnotetext`. I've shown this also in the example.

[image: result]

Note: Inside a `minipage` environment, you have to increase `mpfootnote` instead of `footnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1]\footnote{This was the first lipsum paragraph}
    
    \lipsum[2]\stepcounter{mpfootnote}\footnotetext{\label{ftn}We also have had assecond one.}
    
    \lipsum[3]\footnote{And a third one.}
    
    The invisible footnote was number \ref{ftn}.
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Testfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: inside minipage inside figure]

---

Edit (because of comment): If you really need to use `\footnotetext` without `\footnotemark` but with `\footref` or `\ref` to a label set inside `\footnotetext` (something I would not recommend, because it is inconsistent and strange), you could locally redefine `\thefootnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newcommand*{\footnotenomark}[1]{%
  {\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{}\footnotemark}%
  \footnotetext{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This was the first lipsum paragraph}
\lipsum[4-7]

\lipsum[2]\footnotenomark{\label{ftn}We also have
  a second one.}
\lipsum[4-6]

\lipsum[3]\footnote{And a third one.}

\lipsum[4-5]
The invisible footnote was number \ref{ftn}.
\end{document}
```

But note, if you do not use option `colorlinks` but link frames or underlining links, there would be strange empty frames or underscores.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to work in conjunction with the hyperref package (i.e. clickable hyperlinks). Do you happen to know which further variables I have to tweak (right now it jumps to the last footnote created without the modified method)?

Comment: @Richard There indeed is a problem jumping to the footnote which has no number in the text. But all other links are correct in my tests. So I do not really see a problem, because if you want to reference a footnote the most simple thing is to use either `\footnote`, or `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. And in both cases the link would be correct. So either I've missed something or you've withheld crucial information in your question. Maybe this is even a xy-question. Please show a minimal working example.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, but if I do `\footnotetext{sth. \label{sth}}` and then do `\ref{sth}` the reference will point to the last footnote that was set by the `\footnote` command (or that has a matching `\footnotemark`), neither of which I want.

Comment: @Richard It is absolutely unclear, why you are not using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. However, I've a suggestion even for such strange code.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I defined a new command that uses `footnotetext` and simply adds one to the counter that keeps track of `footnote` numbering.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\invisiblefootnote}[1]{%
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}%
\footnotetext{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \footnote{Text 1}
  \footnote{Text 2}
  \invisiblefootnote{can't see this one}
  \footnote{another one}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are not wanted suspicious spaces in your definition. You need to comment both end of lines inside the definition of `\invisiblefootnote`. → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453

Comment: well spotted. I edited it